# Multipule Operations in a finally block

Tags: c#, exception

Lets say you had some resource clean up like: This is C#.

```
try{/*stuff*/}
catch(Exception e) {/*rollback logs etc.*/}
finally{
 if( context.Transaction != null )
  context.Transaction.Dispose();
 context.Connection.Close();
 context.Connection.Dispose();
}
```

Would it be more robust to do this instead?

```
try{/*stuff*/}
catch(Exception e) {/*rollback logs etc.*/}
finally{
 try{
  if( context.Transaction != null )
   context.Transaction.Dispose();
 }catch(Exception e){/*logs*/}
 finally{
  context.Connection.Close();
  context.Connection.Dispose();
 }
}
```

This way if the transaction.dispose manages to fail at leat the connection will be given the chance to close.

Comment: By that logic, you could probably take this concept of nested try-catch constructs to infinite levels. Would it still sound as robust?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Would it be more robust to do this instead?

You would be better with multiple using blocks.

First, your catch blocks will eat all exceptions and are not needed (can have try ... finally without any catches). Only use catch if you can handle (or add value to) the exception.

But better:

```
using (var resA = GetMeAResourceNeedingCleanUp())
using (var resB = new AnotherResourceNeedingCleanUpn(...)) {
  // Code that might throw goes in here.
}
```

NB. Once an exception is winding back, and finally blocks are clearing up, throwing an other exception is likely to lead to (at best) confusion about which is being handled. This second guideline:

**DO NOT** throw exceptions from Dispose methods or finalizers. If you need to allow users to handle cleanup failures provide a separate Close method which can report its failure.

Note, the "Framework Design Guidelines" (2<sup>nd</sup> ed) has this as (§9.4.1):

> **AVOID** throwing an exception from within Dispose(bool) except under critical
>   situations where the containing process has been corrupted (leaks, inconsistent
>   shared state, etc.).

Comment: I believe your using statements are the wrong way round, given that you usually need to specify the connection to create the transaction for - and that the transaction should usually be cleaned up first.

Comment: Quite possibly (depends on the type of transactions), I was trying to be non-specific about the resources (and failed).

Comment: If you rename trans and con to resource1 and resource2, you can get resource agnostic...

Comment: I was going to wait, but then noticed the missing ')' :-(

Answer (score 3):

Three points:

- You don't need to call Close as well as dispose
- Disposing of the transaction in a separate finally block is a better idea, as it guards against exceptions being thrown during disposal. (It shouldn't happen often, but it might do.)
- The `using` statement is almost always the cleanest way to dispose of resources. I use this even if I *also* want a try/catch block, simply because it's the idiomatic way of saying, "This uses a resource which I want to be disposed at the end of the block"

Combining these would lead to two using statements:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = ...)
{
    using (Transaction trans = ...)
    {
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid excessive indentation, you can write this as:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = ...)
using (Transaction trans = ...)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why would a Dispose call fail? You can also be too careful at some point. Like wrap every 'new' statement with a try/catch in case memory runs out...

Comment: > "why would a Dispose call fail?" 
One example is a FileStream: Dispose attempts to flush the stream which can fail.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like my finally clauses to be too verbose (or any clause, for that matter).  I would refactor your resource cleanup into some utility class.  Keep all the nested try's and "if null" conditions there, so you get better reuse.  For example, because your cleanup logic resides in only one location, you can easily change your mind later about whether you really need to call Dispose().

Even more important, your application code becomes much more comprehensible.

```
try{/*stuff*/}
catch(Exception e) {/*rollback logs etc.*/}
finally{
  Utility.cleanup(context);
}
```